# Applications of combinations with repetition

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

I am having problems understanding how to distinguish some combinatorial questions (specifically **question 2** below). What distinguishes these two types of questions?

In  question 1, I can see that the questions is of the type $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 +...+ x_n = y$ and solve the questions accordingly. But in question 2, I see that it shares similarities (in the choice of wording at least) to question 1 which leads me to assume it is also be solved by setting up the question like $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 +...+ x_n = y$. **But** the question (question 2) has multiple objects (pennies, nickels, dimes etc.) instead of a single unique set such as question 1.

How does one set up an equation to solve question 2 below?

**Question 1**
*In how many ways can 10 (identical) dimes be distributed among five children if;*
a) *there are no restrictions?* 
$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 +x_5 = 10 \\={14\choose10}$

b) *each child gets at least one dime?* 
$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 +x_5 = 5 \\={9\choose5}$

c) *the oldest child gets at least two dimes?*
$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 +x_5 = 8 \\={12\choose8}$

**Question 2**
*In how many ways can we select five coins from a collection of 10 consisting of one penny, one nickel, one dime, one quarter, one half dollar and five (identical) Susan V. Anthony dollars?*

which results with the solution $2^5$

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: In order for us to help you distinguish them, it would help if you pointed out where you see the similarities between them.

Comment: @joriki sorry, I will update my question momentarily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best to solve questions in the naturally easiest way.

$Q1$ is about distributing identical objects to distinct boxes, a typical stars and bars problem.

$Q2$ is about choosing from distinct objects, and the easiest way here is to either select or not select from *pennies, nickels,*... and fill up the needed balance with *dollars*, hence $2^5$

Having said that, we *can* apply stars and bars with inclusion-exclusion in a tortuous way !
Imagine that we have 10 identical objects, and 6 distinct boxes marked *penny*, *nickel*, ... *dollar*, and we need a total of $5$ with the restriction that none except the dollar box can accommodate more than one object.
Then, # of ways = $\binom{10}{5} - \binom51\binom85 + \binom52\binom65 = 32$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that really helps me visualize the math behind it. Cheers.

Comment: You're welcome !